# Ghost blog.url returning wrong URL

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, ghost-blog, ghost

I have a brand new Ghost blog running on DigitalOcean (version 0.8) setup by DigitalOcean's one-click setup.

I have edited the `config.js` file and changed the `url` parameter in `production` to my domain (http://garrypettet.com). Everything seems to be working except that in various places throughout the UI and the theme's output (Casper) I am seeing the root domain listed as `my-ghost-blog-com` instead of `garrypettet.com`. I have searched for the string `my-ghost-blog` in the `config.js` file but I see no reference to it.

Is there some other location I need to change this default to?

Comment: Are you running it in production-mode and have you restarted the Ghost-instance after making the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reedyn was correct. I needed to restart the Ghost instance and then everything worked.